# How to make checkbox clickable from Qtreeview

Tags: qt

[image: Qtreeview checkbox]

```
QStandardItem* item=new QstandardItem();
item->setCheckable(true);
item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

In Qtreeview i have used checkbox .But when i click it,nothing happens.Checkbox is not clickable.

Is there a way to make checkbox clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the proper flags for the item using the [setFlags()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setFlags) method like in the following snippet:

```
QStandardItem* item=new QstandardItem();
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
```

There are several flags you can use to define other behaviors (editing, selection etc.). Check this  [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) for a detailed description of each one. Use the pipe '|' to pack set of flags together, as I did in the example.

If you are using a model for your QTreeView you might need to override the [QAbstractItemModel::flags()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) method as well in your inheriting class.